# How to use linux commands in bash variables

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I am trying to create a bash script to perform the same action of the below command :

```
dig -x 8.8.8.8 | grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5
```

Output is `google-public-dns-a.google.com.`

Now I have created the script test.sh as below :

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$1
output1=$(dig -x $IP)
grepg="grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5"
go=$($output1 | $grepg)
echo $go
```

and called the script as ./test.sh 8.8.8.8. But getting errors. How can I store Linux commands inside bash variables effectively with quotes ?
Thanks

Comment: Ditch bash. Use python

Comment: @ealfonso Ditch python. Write assembly code. Do I win the "cool programmer" contest?

Comment: Python is in quite the opposite direction from assembly code

Comment: @ealfonso Yes, and both are equally irrelevant to this question unless you think that there should only be one programming language in the world and learning any other is a waste of time.

Comment: I used to bash my head against bash and all it's dirtiness, the backticking, the never-ending mess with literals, the slapping together commands with different input/output conventions. Bash is so dirty, that even very simple scripts are better done with python, especially if they are at all expected to grow.

Comment: @ealfonso But why Python? Why not any of the dozens of other high-level programming languages? Because you like it, so we all should too? The OP is trying to understand bash scripting; they can make their own decision about whether it's the right tool for a particular job.

Comment: I'd say that Python offers a pretty good balance between high-level features and the 'instantaneity' that one expects from typical scripting languages. It was my opinion of course, and not a direct answer to his question. Also, the OP's question itself is probably a good example of why bash is such a dirty mess.

Comment: @ealfonso If you'd written something like "consider learning a scripting language such as Python, as bash scripts tend to get messy as they get more complicated", I might not have reacted so snarkily, even if I didn't agree. Your 4-word comment was particularly unconstructive, and laden with assumptions and opinions which you didn't bother to state until I challenged it.

Comment: It honestly doesn't concern me that you would like everyone to be perfectly diplomatic, "reasonable", without a personality. My comment was clearly my own opinion, and it was intended with a bit of flavor to convey an experience of frustration. It works exactly as it is worded, and you seem obsessive and pedantic and I suggest you stop wasting your time.

Comment: Ironically, it is the same absolutism that you claim to challenge in my opinion that you invoke as you try to promote a standard where everyone must show a boring, lame, colorless 'professional' personality. Not everyone cares about that standard, I am sorry to admit

Comment: @ealfonso OK, so you wrote a comment trying to be "colourful", and I responded "colourfully" because I didn't think your comment was particularly helpful (are you going to add it to every question tagged "bash"?). This is a site dedicated to helping people, so being helpful seems like a pretty simple thing to expect.

Comment: I only wish I had received such a helpful suggestion earlier, it would have spared me many frustrations with bash. The reason why I included it here particularly is because 1) I felt like it, 2) OP's struggle seems to illustrate the dirtiness of bash quite clearly.

Comment: >>> re.search("^(?m).*PTR.*?(google.*)$", subprocess.check_output("dig -x 8.8.8.8".split(' '))).group(1)
'google-public-dns-a.google.com.

Comment: @ealfonso Would you really have acted differently based on somebody writing "Ditch bash. Use python" with absolutely zero explanation? I doubt it. I wasn't trying to cramp your style, just suggesting that you include a bit more explanation if you wanted anyone to actually take your advice.

Comment: FWIW, that Python looks a lot uglier to me than the Bash pipeline (and misses the point of the question anyway), but I guess that just goes to show how subjective the whole thing is.

Comment: I actually meant to write "Use python" only but that was too short. The regular expression is clearly more elegant, precise, flexible than piping and cutting a bunch of stuff with hardcoded numbers (what if the command's output decides to add a new word under certain circumstances? that would throw off the whole thing). I agree the one-line looks a bit cluttered, but that is just because it should be broken into two.

Comment: @ealfonso Meh; `cut` might break easier than a regex, it might not - you might have well-defined fields but no idea what was in them. And both shell scripting and Python would let you use both anyway, in multiple different flavours. Like I say, it's all kind of subjective, and that was kind of where this discussion started. I think we both started taking it too seriously somewhere along the line, for which I apologise.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also guilty of taking it a bit too personally. I'm glad that you challenged me, I think a better and more concrete/helpful discussion  came out of this than my original comment could ever have implied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

The first is that you're trying to execute as a command the contents of the variable `$ouptut1`, which is just the `dig` output; it's not a command. You probably meant `echo $output1`.

Then you are trying to execute the contents of variable `$grepg` as a pipeline. But parsing a line into the components of a compound command (a pipeline is a compound command) happens before parameter expansion. So if you execute something like this:

```
foo="echo hello | grep hi"
$foo
```

This first gets broken apart into a single simple command, then the command is expanded, then it is parsed into arguments. So this is equivalent to running:

```
echo hello "|" grep hi
```

In general, it's not a good idea to store strings of text that you want to have evaluated in variables. There are a few very special cases in which you may want to do it, but in almost every case (and probably your case) there's a better way to do it. I'm going to warn you against it, but if you really want to evaluate a string as a command, you can use `eval`, for example:

```
go=$(echo $output1 | eval $grepg)
```

What you seem to want is to define a shell function. If you want to reuse that pipeline several times, running several different values through it, just define a shell function. That function is a single command that acts as the equivalent of the contained commands:

```
function grepg() {
    grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5
}

go=$(echo $output1 | grepg)
```

To simplify your code further, you can avoid all of the intermediate variables. If you're just going to pipe the results of the `dig` command into `grepg`, you don't need to save it in a variable before doing so. And if you're just going to echo the results to stdout, again you don't need to store it in a variable, you can just let the output go to stdout:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$1
function grepg() {
    grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5
}

dig -x $IP | grepg
```

I'm assuming here that you wanted to factor out the function so you could use it several times in your script; if not, if you're just going to use it once, you could simplify further to:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$1
dig -x $IP | grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5
```

Note that if you want to store a pipeline like this in a variable so that you could use some other code to decide between two functions, and apply one or the other depending on some condition, I'd recommend defining the function like above, and then just storing the single function name in the variable. That will work the way you expect:

```
function grepg() {
    grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5
}

function grepf() {
    # do something else, I'm not creative enough to come up with a good example
}

if [ "$2" = "foo" ]
then
    func=grepg
else
    func=grepf
fi

dig -x $IP | $func
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply:

```
dig -x "$1" | grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5
```

Comment: I have used this to convey my doubt clearly. I know it can be done in single step but want to understand how to store the commands inside variables and use for later use.

Answer (score 1):

`output1` stores the results of `dig -x $IP`, not the command itself since you're using `$( )`.

`grepg` stores the command as a string, which is fine but is giving you some unexpected results.

On this line:

```
go=$($output1 | $grepg)
```

it tries to pipe the output from `dig` into a single program called `"grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5"`.

What you probably want is:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$1
output1="dig -x $IP"
grepg="grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5"
go=$(eval $output1 | eval $grepg)
echo $go
```

The `dig` command is stored as a string in `output1`, just like `grepg` stores the other command.

Also, `eval` is needed here as well. Without `eval` it thinks that the entire string is the program name, instead of a program name followed by arguments, pipes, etc.

That means it's looking for a program called `"grep PTR | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep google | cut -f 5"` rather than looking for `grep` followed by an argument, followed by a pipe, and so on.

Comment: Yes this is what I really looked into

Answer (score 0):

Your piped chain of commands can be shortened to a single awk command:

```
dig -x 8.8.8.8 | awk '/PTR[[:space:]]/{print $NF}'
google-public-dns-a.google.com
```

I case you want to search for `google` also in the same line:

```
dig -x 8.8.8.8| awk '/PTR[[:space:]]/ && /google/ {print $NF}'
```

To store its output in a bash variable, use:

```
go=$(dig -x 8.8.8.8| awk '/PTR[[:space:]]/{print $NF}')
```

Comment: @IMSoP: That grep isn't really needed since this IP resolves to `google-public-dns-a.google.com`

Comment: It's pretty clear in the question that 8.8.8.8 is variable, but google is constant. It's not explained why this is necessary, but nor is there evidence that it's not.